# Setting subject variable in Laravel mailables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a mailable `php artisan make:mail SendInEmail`

```
class SendInEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $email;
    public $sub;
    public $emailcontent;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct($email, $sub, $emailcontent)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->sub = $sub;
        $this->emailcontent = $emailcontent;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
         return $this->subject($sub)->view('emails.sendemail');
    }
}
```

In the build function I am passing the `$sub` variable, which comes from the controller, but it gives me an error:

**`Undefined variable: sub`**

When I use this:

```
 return $this->subject('Some subject')->view('emails.sendemail');
```

It works fine.

P.S I did some research and found that I need `use` function to pass the subject variable (some anonymous function magic) (Not sure how to do that with mailables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the wrong variable, so change it to `$this->sub`:

```
return $this->subject($this->sub)->view('emails.sendemail');
```